# How to import Model and Replace AXutil in AX2012?

Tags: powershell, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I would like to import a new model and replace the existing related models.

In Command Promd I used:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\ManagementUtilities"
axutil import /file:"c:\MyModel.axmodel" /server MySQLInstance /database MAPEI_AX63_MYDATABASE_model /replace:MyOLD_Model /conflict:push
```

I get some errors about Database Instance; I think is wrong position.

My Error:

> ERROR: The MySQLInstance command or command line switch is unknown or incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

By Dynamics AX 2012 Management Shell, this command line work:

install-axmodel -noprompt -file "C:\MyModel.axmodel" -server:MySQLInstance -database:MAPEI_AX63_MyDB_model -replace "MyOLD_Model" -conflict:push